# Sending a PendingIntent to activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm trying to monitor this app's notification using `NotificationListenerService`. I want to capture its PendingIntent associated with it's notification and send it to another activity. This activity displays a simple button which launches this captured pendingIntent. How should I transmit this captured PendingIntent across activities?

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    PendingIntent notiPendingIntent = sbn.getNotification().contentIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it. Very simple: just put it as a `Parcelable` using `putExtra()`.